# Quickest way to navigate from my project's files to Angular's source code?

Tags: angular, webstorm

I find myself wanting to navigate from my project code to a specific class in Angular's source code quite often.

For example, let's say that I have the following import in one of my files:

```ts
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

What's the quickest way to navigate to the **TypeScript file** where `RouterModule` is declared, i.e. [router_module.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_module.ts#L123)?

I'm using WebStorm and all of the "Go To..." methods (go to declaration, go to implementation, go to type declaration) take me to the *TypeScript definition file* (in that case, `router_module.d.ts`).

Also, it seems from looking inside the `node_modules/@angular` folder that the `.ts` files are not even present in my project... (which uses Angular CLI).

So what I do right now is manually browse https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/%40angular but it's not ideal.

Any ideas how to improve this workflow?

Comment: I'd like to see this answered as well. Just taking a guess here...is it possible that they only publish the created .js output and the .d.ts files for intellisense/autocomplete to limit the published package size on npm?

Comment: Probably. It does make sense that the `*.ts` are not published; after all, those files are not needed for Angular to do its work. But even if they were included, I think the IDE would still take us to the `d.ts` files.

Comment: Please vote for [IDEA-183550](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183550)